# ISO 8583 message conversion Hexa to string

Tags: crc, iso8583

Currently I am working with a financial institution who get transaction through POS machine. The POS machine is from injenico company. I receive the HEXA message from the POS.

`005B600002000002003020058020C010042100000000000200000000160021000200374520176553390700D20026011539608150000F31303030303030323130303030303030303030303030310000000000000000006303030303036`.

How can I convert this to 8583 message. If I do normal conversion it gives a string:

```
`"‡\0S`\0\0\0\00 € À\0!\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0!\0\07E eS9\a\0Ò\0&9`P\010000002100000000000001\0000006"`
```

I think it is encrypted string.

Can any one give me an idea about conversion of this ?

Comment: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8583.

Answer (score 1):

It is iso8583-1987-like financial message, very similar to **Hypercom POS Data Handler (HPDH)** message.

First two bytes are hex value of message size, then 5 bytes TPDU header, then iso 8583 message itself. Below is the data explanation as it is defined in HPDH specification.

FYI:

- don't use real card data when you share dumps to public, it is
  insecure.
- when you tried to clean PIN block in DE052 (I guess) you lost one
  hexadecimal character, because of this DE062 length was shifted. It
  is fixed in the example parsing.

  ```
  msg:  # Hypercom POS Data Handler (HPDH) Message
   TPDU:  # Transport Protocol Data Unit
    S01: "60" # ID  // Transactions
    S02: "0002" # Address, Destination
    S03: "0000" # Address, Originator
   MTI: "0200" # Message Type ID.  // Financial Transaction Request
   DE000: "3020058020C01004" # Primary bitmap  // 3.4.11.22.24.25.35.41.42.52.62.
   BM0:  # Fields at Primary Bitmap
    DE003:  # PC
     S01: "21" # Transaction Code.  // Payment/Deposit
     S02: "00" # Account, from.  // Default
     S03: "00" # Account, to.  // Default
    DE004: "000000020000" # Amount, transaction.  // 20000
    DE011: "000016" # STAN.  // 16
    DE022:  # POS entry mode
     PAD: "0"
     S01: "02" # PAN entry mode  // MS
     S02: "1" # PIN entry capability  // PIN
    DE024: "0002" # Network International Identifier (NII)
    DE025: "00" # POS condition code  // Normal presentment
    DE035:  # Track 2 Data
     len: "37"
     val: "452017******0700D****6011539608150000F" # Track 2.
    DE041: "10000002" # CATI.
    DE042: "100000000000001" # CAIC.
    DE052: "0000000000000000" # PIN block, encoded.
    DE062:  # Private data
     len: "0006"
     val: 
      v01: "000006" # Invoice/ECR reference number
  ```

Comment: how to  parse this message using java?

Answer (score 0):

Ingenico is just harware manufacturer, you must find out who wrote software for that POS. I guest that this is variation of ISO 8583 v1 (1987).

```
005B6000020000    Maybe some header for packet
0200              MTID
3020058020C01004  BITMAP (3, 4, 11, 22, 24, 25, 35, 41, 42, 52, 62)
210000            F03 Processing code in BCD      
000000020000      F04 Amount in BCD
000016            F11 STAN in BCD
0021              F22 Point of service entry mode in BCD
0002              F24 ?
00                F25 POS condition code in BCD
374520176553390700D20026011539608150000F    F35 Track2 in BCD
3130303030303032313030303030303030303030303031 F41 and F42 in ASCII
0000000000000000  F52 Pinblock (empty)
006303030303036.  F62 Some private data
```

Comment: Hello Tomas, Thank you for your response. I talked with the my hardware supplier about the code, they said it is encode and I shouldn't try to decode it. We change our plan on the implementation and skip this part. But I will personally work on this in future. Thanks again -Zobayer

Comment: Why is it called in BCD? I am a bit confused since whenever I search for BCD it always show binary values.

Comment: It's a shortcut for "binary coded decimal". I suggest looking at those binary values by converting them to a HEX as in that form they are nicely readable.